# I integrated leakcanary with version 2.0-beta-3, app flickered out

Tags: android, leakcanary

Error message -

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider
>   leakcanary.internal.LeakCanaryFileProvider:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "leakcanary.internal.LeakCanaryFileProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip
>   file "/system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar", zip file
>   "/data/app/com.cango.financetob-lH9-QFZ7DnUT7CUjD0oFVQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.cango.financetob-lH9-QFZ7DnUT7CUjD0oFVQ==/lib/arm,
>   /data/app/com.cango.financetob-lH9-QFZ7DnUT7CUjD0oFVQ==/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a,
>   /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]

I only integrated this version in the form of documentation.  And this is the complete code snippet.

// debugImplementation because LeakCanary should only run in debug builds. debugImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:2.0-beta-3'

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. Please provide a code snippet for your issue. And a possible way to reproduce it if possible.

Comment: hey,this is the complete error meesage.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider leakcanary.internal.LeakCanaryFileProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "leakcanary.internal.LeakCanaryFileProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.cango.financetob-lH9-QFZ7DnUT7CUjD0oFVQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.cango.financetob-lH9-QFZ7DnUT7CUjD0oFVQ==/lib/arm, /data/app/com.cango.financetob-lH9-QFZ7DnUT7CUjD0oFVQ==/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]

Comment: I only integrated this version in the form of documentation.And this is the complete code snippet.
 // debugImplementation because LeakCanary should only run in debug builds.
    debugImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:2.0-beta-3'

Answer (score 2):

May be you are using `aspectjx` on the same time. So you need to add content:

```
android{
    ...
}
aspectjx {
    ...
    exclude 'com.squareup.leakcanary'
}
```

at

```
app/buid.gradle
```

then **clean** or **Invalidate Caches / Restart**

Answer (score 0):

This happens when version is not supported by your app. Try lowering LeakCanary version (2.0_beta) to lower versions. Ideally this should fix.

-This worked for me.